# I was given a multiple-entry business Schengen visa, but for 5 days. Why?

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry, business-travel

It feels like I'm being trolled.

I did everything by the book, travel insurance valid for a year, solid supporting docs (even though the application centre gave half of them back before sending to the Embassy), signed letters from the boss, and from the inviting company. In those letters it explicitly states that I will have to make multiple trips to the Schengen area.

What could have gone wrong?

What's the point of granting me a multiple-entry visa, if the validity is only for 5 days?

What can I do next time to prevent this?

Comment: I suppose that you provided a detailed itinerary at least for your first planned trip in your visa application. Does your first trip require a multiple entry visa? You don't tell where you are coming from and how long you are planning to stay, but I can think of many situations, in which a 5 day multiple entry visa could make sense.

Comment: Coming from London. It's one trip, and I gave them the return flight tickets.

Comment: And that single, first trip is for five days? I mean, if you are flying into the Schengen area from London e.g. only for daily meetings, the visa you have been issued, would allow you to attend five such meetings.

Comment: It is one single trip for five days, I also had proof of accommodation for where I would be staying for the duration of the stay.

Answer (score 6):

It is common practice to give long, multiple entry visa only after a few successful visits on shorter visa. So if the validity period of your visa matches the *first* of your planned visits, that would appear normal. They expect you to apply again for the next one, and perhaps again for the one after that, before you get long-validity multiple-entry visa.

Only the multiple entry combined with the short validity looks a bit unusual.

Comment: I have quite a comprehensive peripatetic history for my age, plus I studied in Switzerland for the past 4 years so it seems strange that my risk profile would be high enough to warrant such a short validity. Coupled with the fact that they made it multiple entry, leaves me really confused.

Comment: @ThePanzer The fact that you studied in Switzerland might make them more wary about the possibility that you might want to stay in Europe.

Comment: Surely the fact that I left Switzerland after my graduation shows that I'm not planning to illegally immigrate? My visa expired in September, and I left in July. I also sent them a proof of employment letter.

Comment: How long ago were you in Switzerland?

Comment: July of this year

Comment: @phoog, if they were worried about overstaying, they wouldn't let him in once. More likely they simply went "any recent C? No? OK, short validity."